# Java: reflection to invoke methods in a nonpublic class that implements a public interface

Tags: java, reflection

I'm trying to use reflection to invoke a method whose name and arguments are known at runtime, and I'm failing with an `IllegalAccessException`.

This is on an object that is an instance of a nonpublic class which implements a public interface, and I've got a brain cramp trying to remember the right way to invoke such a method.

```
public interface Foo
{
    public int getFooValue();
}

class FooImpl implements Foo
{
    @Override public int getFooValue() { return 42; }
}

Object foo = new FooImpl();
```

Given the `foo` object, how would I call foo.getFooValue() reflectively?

If I look through the results of `foo.getClass().getMethods()`, this should work but I think it causes the `IllegalAccessException` Is this a case where I have to call `getDeclaredMethods()`? Or do I have to walk through the public interfaces/superclasses and call `getDeclaredMethods` there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works:

```
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

public class Ex
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        final String methodName = "getFooValue";
        Object foo = new FooImpl();
        Class<?> c = foo.getClass();
        Method m = c.getDeclaredMethod(methodName, null);
        System.out.println(m.invoke(foo));
    }
}

interface Foo
{
    public int getFooValue();
}

class FooImpl implements Foo
{
    @Override public int getFooValue() { return 49; }
}
```

Comment: blech, I have to walk the interfaces + subclasses then to find a method that works.

Comment: Hmm. It seems I haven't stated the question well. I'll accept and try again.

Comment: I'm also facing this problem. Have you already created another question?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should call the getDeclaredMethods().

[Here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Programming/Reflection/Accessing_Private_Features_with_Reflection)'s an example:

```
Method methods[] = secretClass.getDeclaredMethods(); 
System.out.println("Access all the methods"); 
for (int i = 0; i < methods.length; i++) { 
   System.out.println("Method Name: " + methods[i].getName());
   System.out.println("Return type: " + methods[i].getReturnType());
   methods[i].setAccessible(true);
   System.out.println(methods[i].invoke(instance, EMPTY) + "\n");
}
```

By the way, a post refering to '[private classes reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5951197/accessing-private-inner-class-in-the-same-package/5952096#5952096)':

> When it comes to bytecode (i.e. runtime) there is no such thing as a private class. This is a fiction maintained by the compiler. To the reflection API, there's a package-accessible type with a public member method.